# Function overloading with initialization_list causing ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, language-lawyer, overloading

I am trying to overload function with initialization_list as parameters with variation to accept map and vector along with an integer. The compiler complains that the function resolution is ambiguous. I am wondering what causes the ambiguity and how to resolve it

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <initializer_list>

std::shared_ptr<int> foo(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<int> > >& il)
{
    return std::make_shared<int>();
}
std::shared_ptr<int> foo(const std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<int> > & il)
{
    return std::make_shared<int>();
}

std::shared_ptr<int> foo(int num)
{
    return std::make_shared<int>();
}

int main()
{
    foo({ { "a", foo(10) } });
}
```

[Try It OUT >>>](http://ideone.com/AZ2DF3)

**Note**

1. I tried with VS2013 as well as g++ and both of them errors out.
2. As per @chris the above code compiles in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba2cf5502b55095a)
3. What does the standard say? Or does it actually say anything?

Comment: [Compiles with Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba2cf5502b55095a).

Comment: @chris [libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eea635a75a390a2f) only seems to give the error.

Comment: The standard does have the precondition: Requires: p shall be convertible to T*. I don't know what it requires implementations to do about preconditions, though. I would wager that both libstdc++ (which presumably doesn't use SFINAE) and libc++ (which does) are both correct.

Comment: @chris: If compilers are not required to implement preconditions then it could be confusing. My guess was, the pointers are not convertible so should not be an ambiguous call.

Comment: @chris Violations of *requires* sections yield UB. SFINAE is mandated in a *remarks* clause.

Comment: @Abhijit, Honestly, I would consider relying on a compiler error when the pointers are not convertible as enforcing the precondition pretty well. It says nothing about how overload resolution is affected.

Comment: @dyp So we're indirectly incurring UB?

Comment: @templateboy It seems so, yes. Maybe the Standard *should* mandate SFINAE instead; the OP's issue is probably relatively new, since it relies on list-initialization. On the other hand, passing a parameter to a function using list-initialization might be considered weird enough not to bother the library implementers and declare this a QoI issue.

Answer (score 3):

> what causes the ambiguity

`shared_ptr` has a constructor with two arguments:

```
template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);
```

which matches the initialiser list `{ "a", foo(10) }` as well as a `pair` does. (Or, if not as well, then close enough for some compilers to get it wrong. The exact rules melt my brain, so I won't try to figure out which compiler is technically correct.)

> how to resolve it

Assuming you want the first overload, provide a `pair` type, rather than a more general initialiser list:

```
foo({ std::make_pair( "a", foo(10) ) });
```

> What does the standard say? Or does it actually say anything?

It says a lot, often in rather opaque language. I can't quote the twenty pages of [over.match], and don't have the language-lawyer skills to summarise how they apply here while retaining my sanity.

Comment: It looks like libc++ takes this overload out of the set if the pointer is not convertible: `template<class _Yp, class _Dp>
        shared_ptr(_Yp* __p, _Dp __d,
                   typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Yp*, element_type*>::value, __nat>::type = __nat());`

Comment: It is an invalid constructor for `shared_ptr` but that does not mean that the other overload should be called, it depends on how you implement "The expression d(p) shall be well formed" and how that interacts with your overload resolution rules. It could be that the tighter matching of `Y*` could override the inability to satisfy the constraint on the second parameter (since it matched the template).

Comment: As @chris quoted that there is a pre-condition that the pointers needs to be convertible which in this case is not, I am wondering if its close enough or the pre-condition has been inadvertently omitted. In the later case, we can raise a bug report. [Note, your answer as it stands does not explain about pointer convertibility so cannot accept, but would do so if you add more clarity]

Comment: @abhijit: Sorry, that's all the clarity I can give. I've explained why a compiler might find it ambiguous, and how to make it completely unambiguous. You'll need a much higher-level language lawyer to judge which implementations are correct.